# How to have badge on a ListView's children withou clipping in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Hello I want badges on children of a ListView but the badges are clipped because of their right neighbor ? How can I get this to work ?

Here is the code:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: -10,
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is a screen:

[image]

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

On your stack widget use `Clip.none`, default is `Clip.hardEdge`

```dart
 return Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes thanks this is much better but is is still a bit clipped behind the blue Container it is more visible if you reduce the padding in my previous example with for example 4.
Do you know a way to change this behavior ?
It seems like this is a rendering order problem because this does not append if I set reversed to true in the ListView, but obviously it also reverse the list order.

Comment: The positioned -10 refer to right being negative beyond view, while the padding only cover 8px from top, we need to cover extra 20px being positioned -10 right. You can increase width to solve this. `width: 40 + 20,`. I will prefer using fixed width from  itemBuilder and place widget.

Comment: If I understand well there is no way to overflow on the right on top on my right neighbor and being draw on top, the only way is to increase the size of my Container so the "badge" fits in my box ?
This force to have space between items.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?  you may like to have `reverse:true` on listView, if fails consider include an image that you are trying to get